# abort() not called on JAAS login module with security property sufficient

Tags: java, jaas, activemq-artemis

JAAS module in the ActiveMQ Artemis broker is not calling `abort()` function when authentication fails when using the `sufficient` flag. It's calling `commit()` even though it throws `FailedLoginException`. But if I change the security property to `requisite` or `required` in the `login.config` file `abort()` is called when it throws `FailedLoginException`. Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [relevant JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html) says this about the `sufficient` flag:

> [A sufficient] LoginModule is not required to succeed.  If it does succeed, control immediately returns to the application (authentication does not proceed down the LoginModule list). If it fails, authentication continues down the LoginModule list.
>
> ...
>
> The overall authentication succeeds only if all *Required* and *Requisite* LoginModules succeed. If a Sufficient LoginModule is configured and succeeds, then only the *Required* and *Requisite* LoginModules prior to that *Sufficient* LoginModule need to have succeeded for the overall authentication to succeed. If no *Required* or *Requisite* LoginModules are configured for an application, then at least one *Sufficient* or *Optional* LoginModule must succeed.

In other words, `sufficient` modules are not required to succeed therefore when they fail it appears that `abort()` is not called by design.

For what it's worth, it's the JVM itself which invokes `abort()`, `commit()`, etc. based on the outcome of `login()`. The fact that the login module is being used in ActiveMQ Artemis isn't really relevant.

Comment: I guess in that case, I can pass Requisite/Required flag with my custom JAAS flag. But, if I do that I am not able to login to the Artemis management console(jolokia,port:8163). I have special business logic in custom JAAS which authenticate mobile devices. But, at the same time I want to have admin user who can login to artemis management console with some username/paswword or even without password. Inorder to have both custom and guest login module in artemis login.config, I have to keep security flag of custom Jaas module as sufficient atleast. how can I handle this situation ?

Comment: This is really a different question which could have a whole discussion of its own. I suggest you create a new question with a full explanation of your use-case.

Comment: I have post my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62366531/jolokia-access-with-custom-jaas