# Jolokia access with custom JAAS

Tags: security, jaas, activemq-artemis

In ActiveMQ Artemis when I use the `requisite` or `required` flag with my custom JAAS login module I am not able to login to the Artemis management console (Jolokia, port `8163`). I have special business logic in the custom JAAS login module which authenticates mobile devices. But at the same time I want to have an admin user who can login to Artemis management console with some username/password or even without password. In order to have both custom and guest login module in Artemis `login.config`, I have to keep the security flag of custom JAAS module as `sufficient` at-least. How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security "realm" used by Hawtio is configured via the `hawtio.realm` system property set in `etc/artemis.profile`. For example, here is the default:

```
JAVA_ARGS=" -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms512M -Xmx2G -Dhawtio.realm=activemq  -Dhawtio.offline=true -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=${ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI}jolokia-access.xml -Djon.id=amq"
```

Here the `hawtio.realm` is set to `activemq` which matches the entry in the default `login.config`, e.g.:

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";

   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.GuestLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.user="myUser"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.role="amq";
};
```

I don't see any reason why you couldn't add a new realm/domain specifically for Hawtio to your `login.config` and then change the configuration in `artemis.profile` to reference that. That way you can customize security for Hawtio connections and messaging connections however you wish.

Also, it's worth noting that Artemis recently added support for per-acceptor security domains. You can read more about this in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#per-acceptor-security-domains).

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin. I was missing realm settings, this works.